# Save content editable HTML table in multiple fields

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x

I need to develop a HTML table where one of the table column is editable on its row and the table row is dynamic in term of the row number.
I come across a problem where when I automate the saveEdits() function, the code is not working.

Here is my code, where the 'cnt' is a dynamic numeric number. Example cnt=50

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

table ,tr td{
    border:1px solid #dddddd;
    padding: 8px;
}
tbody {
    display:block;
    height:600px;
    overflow:auto;
}
thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveEdits(cnt) {
    //get the editable elements.
    var str_out = ''
    while (cnt>0){
        str1 = '\'edit' + cnt + '\': document.getElementById(\'edit' + cnt + '\').innerHTML,\n'
        str_out = str_out.concat(' ', str1);
        cnt--;
    };

    var editElems= { str_out };
    
    alert(editElems)

    //save the content to local storage. Stringify object as localstorage can only support string values
    localStorage.setItem('userEdits', JSON.stringify(editElems));

}
function checkEdits(){
    //find out if the user has previously saved edits
    var userEdits = localStorage.getItem('userEdits');

    alert(userEdits) // suppose to print {"edit1":"  rpeyy7<br>","edit2":"  tpruiiy<br>","edit3":"  opty<br>"}

    if(userEdits){
        userEdits = JSON.parse(userEdits);
        for(var elementId in userEdits){
            document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = userEdits[elementId];
        }
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkEdits()">
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#A9A9A9"  > Field#1 </td>
    <td style="background-color:#A9A9A9" > Field#2 </td>
    <td style="background-color:#A9A9A9" > Field#3- Each Row Under field#3 is content EditableByUser </td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

// Here is the python code that loop through a diectionary content
cnt = 0
for c in sorted(data_dict.keys()) :
    cnt += 1
    <tr>
    <td> {0}    </td>  //Field#1
    <td> {0}    </td>  //Field#2
    ...
    ...

    <td id="edit{0}" contenteditable="true" onKeyUp="saveEdits({0});"> {1} </td>\n'.format(cnt,comment)]
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

I'm not sure where goes wrong as when I automate the saveEdits() function with 'cnt' in while loop, the above code doesn't works for me. But when I defined each row clearly like below, the data the keyed-in are properly saved to each column.

```
function saveEdits(cnt) {

    //get the editable elements.
    var editElems = {
        'edit1': document.getElementById('edit1').innerHTML,
        'edit2': document.getElementById('edit2').innerHTML,
        'edit3': document.getElementById('edit3').innerHTML,
    };
    alert(editElems) //print [object Object]

    //save the content to local storage. Stringify object as localstorage can only support string values
    localStorage.setItem('userEdits', JSON.stringify(editElems));

}
```

I would be much appreciate if someone can point out my mistake. The error is very much likely on saveEdits(cnt) function but I'm not sure how to fix that cause it I define each count 1 by 1, each update that being keyed-in is actually saved properly and able to retrieve when rerun. Thanks you!

Comment: What do you want to happen? Also perhaps you should test using a plain old js array var as your "storage" before going the local storage route.

Comment: Thanks for respond. In the table at column Field#3, it will be a n count of rows which allow user to edit. But as far I only manage to save the edit only each row is defined explicitly like the snippet I gave above. When I try to automate it within a while loop, the system seem not able to recognize each item, in other word doesn't recognize the var editElems in the saveEdits(cnt) function.

Comment: This may be obvious to you after the fact, but shouldn't `edit{0}` be `edit{cnt}` and the like where else applicable as opposed to literal index `0`

Comment: The {0} is actually referring to cnt variable in python.. that part is correct.

Comment: Seems like an illogical language construct. So if you had a `cnt2` how would that be written ? `{1}` ? .... I'd suggest you check your rendered source (Ctrl + U) to see if indeed `{0}` magically applies to `cnt`. Its a python for loop so wouldnt the "magic" apply to the for loop vars?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the cnt part is correct as that is reading from python. Above snippet is not giving out the entire detail of the code, but the construction is correct. I slot in HTML code in between lines of my python coding.